# How can I pass these Array List values between two activities?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to pass a couple of values from the activity "Example" to the other activity "MemberExample.class"

I know this seems like an easy question, that has been answered many times before, but as shown in the code below and I will try to explain, it doesn't seem to be as easy as it looks.

Below is the first activity code that I'm trying to pass but it gets the "mImagesUrl", "mName", "mParties" from a recycler view adapter. I'm not sure where in either class I am meant to put the "putIntent" and "getExtras" methods. Do I put them in the RecyclerView Adapter or the activity class?

Example.class

```
public class Example extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<String> mNames = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> mParties = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> mImageUrls = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.example);


        getImages();
    }

    private void getImages() {


        mImageUrls.add("https://data.oireachtas.ie/ie/oireachtas/member/id/Kathleen-Funchion.D.2016-10-03/image/large");
        mNames.add("Kathleen Funchion");
        mParties.add("Sinn Féin");

        mImageUrls.add("https://data.oireachtas.ie/ie/oireachtas/member/id/John-Paul-Phelan.S.2002-09-12/image/large");
        mNames.add("John Paul Phelan");
        mParties.add("Fine Gael");



        initExampleRV();
    }

    private void initExampleRV() {

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv_Example);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, MemberExample.class);

//?????????????????????



            }

        });
        ClareMembersRecyclerView adapter = new ClareMembersRecyclerView(this, mNames, mParties, mImageUrls);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Adapter.class

```
public class RecyclerView extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ClareMembersRecyclerView.ViewHolder>{


    private  static final  String TAG = "ClareMembersRV";

    //vars
    private ArrayList<String> mNames = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> mParties = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> mImageUrls = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context mContext;

    public RecyclerView(Context context, ArrayList<String> names, ArrayList<String> parties, ArrayList<String> imageUrls){

        mNames = names;
        mParties = parties;
        mImageUrls = imageUrls;
        mContext = context;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateViewHolder: called.");

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_members_clare, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: called.");

    Glide.with(mContext)
            .asBitmap()
            .load(mImageUrls.get(position))
            .into(holder.image);

    holder.name.setText(mNames.get(position));

    holder.party.setText(mParties.get(position));

    holder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: clicked on an image" + mNames.get(position));
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Profile: " + mNames.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MembersMapDetailed.class);
            intent.putExtra(mNames.get(position),mParties,mImageUrls);
                    }
    });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mImageUrls.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        CircleImageView image;
        TextView name;
        TextView party;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgClareCircle);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvClareName);
            party = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvClareParty);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You want to pass all names, parties and imageurls to the other activity? Then what does the recyclerview have to do with it? Also, is it intentional that you set an onclicklistener on the whole recyclerview in your activity?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start a new activity and pass them these values wherever user click on recycle view, you can do it like this:

```
recyclerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, MemberExample.class);
     intent.putExtra("EXTRA_KEY_NAMES", mNames);
     intent.putExtra("EXTRA_KEY_PARTIES", mParties);
     intent.putExtra("EXTRA_KEY_IMAGES", mImageUrls);
     startActivity(intent);
  }
```

If you want to start a new activity and pass values, based on the item that the user clicked in the previous activity you can use `onItemClickListener`. I think that it is more useful and it is what you want to do, but maybe I am wrong.:

```
recyclerView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, MemberExample.class);
     intent.putExtra("EXTRA_KEY_NAME", mNames.get(position);
     intent.putExtra("EXTRA_KEY_PARTY", mParties.get(position));
     intent.putExtra("EXTRA_KEY_IMAGE", mImageUrls.get(position));
     startActivity(intent);
  }
```

To get these values from intent in your new activity you need to write this part of code in your MemberExample.class:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        ArrayList<String> mNames = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("EXTRA_KEY_NAMES");
        ArrayList<String> mParties = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("EXTRA_KEY_PARTIES");
        ArrayList<String> mImageUrls = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("EXTRA_KEY_IMAGES");
        // Or in second proposed by me solution (with passing single item):
        //String mName = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_KEY_NAME");
        //String mParty = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_KEY_PARTY");
        //String mImage = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_KEY_IMAGE");
}
```

Comment: the "setOnItemClickListener" from "recyclerView.setOnItemClickListener" is creating an error even though I've implemented the method. Do you know why? Thanks for your help by the way

Comment: Let's edit your question and paste there some code.